Is it safe to manipulate a member variable from another member variable during object destruction?
Consider the following code, where we're trying to trigger some action when an object is destroyed (a kind of RAII):
struct Finalizer
{
    std::function<void()> fun;  // <-- this is invoked at destruction
    ~Finalizer() { fun(); }
    Finalizer(const Finalizer&) = delete;
    Finalizer(Finalizer&&) = delete;
    Finalizer& operator=(const Finalizer&) = delete;
    Finalizer& operator=(Finalizer&&) = delete;
};
struct Iface
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
struct Class
{
    Iface& iface;                             // <-- guaranteed to be destroyed after "fin"
    Finalizer fin{[this] { iface.foo(); }};   // <-- hence, this is always safe, right?
};

Suppose we use it roughly like this:
struct IfaceImpl : Iface
{
    void foo() final { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    IfaceImpl impl;
    Class ty{impl};
}

My question is: is it always safe? Assume that the iface reference is valid at the time of destruction.
I initially assumed that it is safe, but then I encountered an interesting issue where both GCC 14 and Clang 18 generate code that segfaults at the virtual call to Iface unless I capture the specific field instead of this:
    Finalizer fin{[&ifc = this->iface] { ifc.foo(); }};

Sadly it is hard to reproduce this in an MWE so I decided to take a theoretical approach first. I suspect that the problem might be due to the fact that the destructor of this is invoked first, which technically invalidates the object state even though the member variable destructors are not yet executed; hence, accessing this->iface is technically not safe.

No problem. Members are destructed at the end of your destructor, so they are still around inside your destructor. C++ is generally quite explicit about things like "what happens when". Destruction also happens in reverse order of construction, so basically "bottom up" when it comes to members.

Looks good to me, too, for what it's worth. Your real code that crashes must be different somehow.

note that your Class is now non-relocatable because your are storing this, which is satisfied because Finalizer cannot be copied, if your real code allows Finalizer to be copyable or moveable then you have a bug and this might be dangling.

Note also that your Class contains a reference to an Iface object, not an Iface object instance, so you must independently guarantee that the Iface object instance that you are referencing lives longer than the Class instance that references it. When the Class object is destructed, the reference member gets destructed, not the referred to object.
